# A material i applied doesnt show up in a render even though its visible in material viewport

Tags: materials

[image: the material hatching doesnt seem to show up in rendered view just the basic colour.]
the material hatching doesnt seem to show up in rendered view just the basic colour. I've tried adjusting the scale of the material but its still not visible. this is inspite of the hatching showing up in the material viewport.
Please help

Comment: Hello :). This can happen when your mesh doesn't have a proper *UV Map*. The *preview* doesn't have anything to do with your model.

Comment: Thanks so much... it was a really dumb question but i completely forgot about uv unwrapping it till you mentioned it... :D

Comment: Happy to help :). There are no dumb questions, good luck with your project.